# Facebook's Hackbook integration in an iOS5 app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Hackbook sample app in an iOS5 ARC enabled app. I'm using the APIResultsViewController from Facebook's sample Hackbook app. My app is ARC enabled, so I made sure that the files I'm using from Hackbook have the `-fno-objc-arc` added as a Compiler flag. The errors I'm getting now are `Use of undeclared identifer 'jsonWriter'; did you mean SBJSonWriter'?` and `Unknown receiver 'jsonWriter'`

I have the SBJSON from the src folder from Facebook API. I was able to get the Facebook Api working in my app. I then wanted to use the features and code from Hackbook sample. After moving the code over those errors popped up. thanks for your help

here's the code where the errors are occuring

```
* Graph API: Check in a user to the location selected in the previous view.
 */
- (void)apiGraphUserCheckins:(NSUInteger)index {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    NSDictionary *coordinates = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [[[myData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"latitude"],@"latitude",
                                  [[[myData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"longitude"],@"longitude",
                                  nil];

    NSString *coordinatesStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:coordinates];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [[myData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"id"], @"place",
                                   coordinatesStr, @"coordinates",
                                   @"", @"message",
                                   nil];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/checkins"
                                    andParams:params
                                andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                  andDelegate:self];
}
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

This seems obvious but do you have SBJSON included as a Framework in your app? http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Comment: I have the SBJSON from the src folder from Facebook API. I was able to get the Facebook Api working in my app. I then wanted to use the features and code from Hackbook sample. After moving the code over those errors popped up. thanks for your help